# Socket.io runs fine locally, but not found on Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, socket.io

I'm fairly new to Node.js, and trying to build an application for myself. I am using socket.io and it works perfectly fine locally during testing, but when I deploy to Azure I keep getting

`http://domain/socket.io/socket.io.js 404 (Not Found)`

I have tried most methods and fixes I could find on forums but nothing seems to work, web sockets is enabled on Azure.

My code as below:

**Client side**:

`<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

**Server side**

```
var express = require('express');
var port = process.env.port || 1337;
var app = require('express')()
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server, { log: false });

server.listen(port);
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you include the modules?

The easiest way is to create a package.json file (`npm init`) and then include that alongside your app.js.

See http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/nodejs-use-node-modules-windows-azure-apps/

Answer (score 1):

To just get it working, try configuring your socket.io client and server to force xhr-polling transport. By default socket.io tries websockets first, and they require some custom configuration for Node.js apps running under iisnode (e.g. in Windows Azure Web Sites).

Running socket.io apps with WebSockets in Windows Azure Web Sites requires a bit of special configuration: http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2013/01/hosting-socketio-websocket-apps-in-iis.html.

For code samples see https://github.com/tjanczuk/dante.

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a go tonight. Will update post if a success.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Azure has three different compute methods in which you could be deploying this application, could you clarify which you're deploying to? Cloud Services, Virtual Machines or Web Sites.

also, could you post your web.config file?

Comment: I am deploying to a Web site, just taking advantage of Azures free services while I teach myself node.js. I currently do not have a web.config on the host. It is suppose to be auto-created when finding the server.js file, but logging in via FTP reveals no web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it work on an azure website, If you have enabled websockets on azure the only thing I have found so far to solve that is to add a web.config in which you will add:

```
<webSocket enabled="false" />
```